# Bootstrap, contact_php and contact.js not sending email

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap and wanting to use an email contact form. I have setup a test page - http://www.beatrootonline.co.uk/test.html. As you can see its validating ok (jqBootstrapValidation.js) and appears to send an email. However, I am not receiving an email from this form.

Heres the html

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-12">
<form name="sentMessage" id="contactForm" novalidate>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
<div class="form-group">
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Name *" id="name" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your name.">
<p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Email *" id="email" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your email address.">
<p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<input type="tel" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Phone *" id="phone" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your phone number.">
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
<div class="form-group">
 <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Your Message *" id="message" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter a message."></textarea>
</div>
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
<div id="success"></div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-xl">Send Message</button>
</div></div>
</form>
</div>
</div>
```

and the contact_me.js
    $(function() {

```
$("input,textarea").jqBootstrapValidation({
    preventSubmit: true,
    submitError: function($form, event, errors) {
        // additional error messages or events
    },
    submitSuccess: function($form, event) {
        event.preventDefault(); // prevent default submit behaviour
        // get values from FORM
        var name = $("input#name").val();
        var email = $("input#email").val();
        var phone = $("input#phone").val();
        var message = $("textarea#message").val();
        var firstName = name; // For Success/Failure Message
        // Check for white space in name for Success/Fail message
        if (firstName.indexOf(' ') >= 0) {
            firstName = name.split(' ').slice(0, -1).join(' ');
        }
        $.ajax({
            url: "bin/contact_me.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                name: name,
                phone: phone,
                email: email,
                message: message
            },
            cache: false,
            success: function() {
                // Success message
                $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-success'>");
                $('#success > .alert-success').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
                    .append("</button>");
                $('#success > .alert-success')
                    .append("<strong>Your message has been sent. </strong>");
                $('#success > .alert-success')
                    .append('</div>');

                //clear all fields
                $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
            },
            error: function() {
                // Fail message
                $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-danger'>");
                $('#success > .alert-danger').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
                    .append("</button>");
                $('#success > .alert-danger').append("<strong>Sorry " + firstName + ", it seems that my mail server is not responding. Please try again later!");
                $('#success > .alert-danger').append('</div>');
                //clear all fields
                $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
            },
        })
    },
    filter: function() {
        return $(this).is(":visible");
    },
});

$("a[data-toggle=\"tab\"]").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).tab("show");
});
});


/*When clicking on Full hide fail/success boxes */
$('#name').focus(function() {
$('#success').html('');
```

and my contact_me.php

```
    <?php
    // check if fields passed are empty
    if(empty($_POST['name'])        ||
    empty($_POST['email'])      ||
    empty($_POST['message'])    ||
   !filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
   {
    echo "No arguments Provided!";
    return false;
   }

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email_address = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

// create email body and send it    
$to = 'me@myaddress.com'; // put your email
$email_subject = "Contact form submitted by:  $name";
$email_body = "You have received a new message. \n\n".
                  " Here are the details:\n \nName: $name \n ".
                  "Email: $email_address\n Message \n $message";
$headers = "From: noreply@myaddress.com\n";


$headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address"; 
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
return true;            
?>
```

I get a successful message on screen to say that the email has been sent but no email arrives (I have substituted my real email address for a fake on the php)

Comment: are you on a shared or dedicated server? do you have php mail set up? have you checked the mail logs on your server?

Comment: you cant send mail from your localhost

Comment: I had a typo in the contact.php code in line 12 (not shown in the example above) just removed it, uploaded and it works!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to put the `mail()` function in condition like :

```
if (mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers)){
    return true;
}else{
    return false;
}
```

So you can check if the mail is sent or not.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that contact_me.php sends mail after loading it manually. Mail function would work only in certain web hosts. You need to enable it manually before you can start sending mails.

Answer (score 0):

Try using PHPMailer. You can find it  [here](https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer). It's much more safer and much more reliable than simple mail function.

Answer (score 0):

I had a typo in the contact.php code in line 12 (not shown in the example above) just removed it, uploaded and it works!! – Thanks everyone!